# Set get of Object.defineProperty does not work properly undefined is printed

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to manage object's properties via set get in defineProperty?

I'm not sure that I'm using this sentence properly.

```
<div id="app"></div>
why
<script>
    var div = document.querySelector('#app');
    var viewModel = {};

    Object.defineProperty(viewModel, 'str' , {
        get: function() {
            return console.log("access");
        },
        set: function() {
            return console.log("setting");              
        }
    })

</script>
```

Comment: this is console.log 

What should I return?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have run `viewModel.go` in console - you will get "access" printed in console, but later you will get `undefined` as it is a result of this `get` function:

```
function() {
     console.log("access");
}
```

This function doesn't have a return clause, so value of `go` will be `undefined`.

Comment: I don't understand well Can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: It is working correctly now, what you would like to achieve? If you would like to set `.go` value to "access", you may use `get: function () { return "access" }`

Comment: thanks for answer but I think people think this question is wrong. What can I do?

Comment: I think that you should not worry about it :) In my opinion this question has a "desired output" designed with "When I typed viewModel.go and hit enter, I expected "access" to be printed. However, undefined is the output."

Comment: I'll try again based on what you told me. Thank you.